# Get information about file attachment via perl Mechanize

Tags: perl, mechanize

**BACKGROUND**

I am experimenting with Mechanize on a web forum.  The forum has some file attachments in its threads.  The attachment can be of various media types.  Each attachment has a link to a server-side program called "attachment.php?" and a unique id which identifies the file.  When you visit it in a normal browser, a file is returned and the browser decides what to do with it.  If it's an image, the file is displayed in the browser window and the titlebar is set to the filename.  If it's another type of file, the browser will ask if you want to download the file (and it automatically sets the filename to the name of the file).

**QUESTION**

My question is how can I explore the details of such file attachments with Mechanize so that I can determine filetype and filename?
I've already successfully downloaded a file using my program, but I have to tell Mechanize what the filename should be.  I would prefer to keep the original filename, but to do that I have to be able to discover it somehow.  I know it can be done because my browser is able to determine the filetype and filename.
As a secondary objective I would also like to query the size of the file, if this is possible.

I hope my question makes sense and thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to answer.

Comment: Generally you want to show details of what you are doing -- in this case, that code that you say you have.  Code, always.  A short (minimal) version that makes the question concrete and specific. Otherwise I find your question to be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment zdim. In this case my question concerned a programming approach as opposed to a problem with a specific piece of code, and that's why I didn't post my existing code.

Comment: ...But I accept your criticism and will post code excerpts in all cases from now on

Comment: I understand that.  It's not really criticism, more information.  Always show your code.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve an inspection of the filetype you have to use `$mech->res()`.  It returns an [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/HTTP-Message-6.11/lib/HTTP/Response.pm) object, and this class provides the `filename` method.

Example:

```
foreach (@media)
{   
    print "Fetching " . $_->url() . "\n";
    $m->get($_);
    my $res = $m->res();
    if($res->is_success)
    {
        my $filename = $res->filename();
        print "$filename\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  I have removed this unnecessary text from the answer.

Comment: Note that people _do not_ have to provide explanations for their votes. Sometimes they'll convey their assessment by votes alone, and it's up to you to figure out why you get +/-. Perhaps not ideal, but it is some feedback.  I've banged my head against that many times. Occasionally, you'll get votes which are hard to understand, but overall there are good reasons.

Comment: Stating that one needs `$mech->res()` doesn't explain why it helps.  One can figure that out from the code, but why not state that. I edited, please clean up/adjust as you like. (Or revert to the previous version, if you don't like it. :)  You can manipulate version control by clicking on _edited ..._ above the user name.

Comment: I prefer your adjustments, thanks for taking the time to help improve my question/answer. I will take this on board for future questions. Cheers.

Comment: If you want to go into more detail, maybe include where it gets that information. There sometimes is an HTTP header in the response that contains the original filename, and the type can also be inferred from the content type header.